# Creating default object from empty value for information

Tags: php, database, laravel

I'm trying to edit and save some articles, but I receive this error : `Creating default object from empty value`. What's wrong in my code?Because, at edit I have my `subject`, but and submit I get this error.
**My error :** https://i.stack.imgur.com/VM89l.jpg
**Controller**

```
public function update($type, $id)

    {
        /* print_r(Input::all()); die;  */
        if($type == "News")
        {
            $article = \App\News::find($id);
            $article->subject = Request::input('subject');
            $article->public = Request::input('public');
            $article->category_id = Request::input('category_id');
            $article->information = Request::input('information');
            $article->update();
        }


        if($type == "Event")
        {

            $article = \App\Event::find($id);
            $article->subject = Request::input('subject');
            $comm->comments = Request::input('comments');
            $article->public = Request::input('public');
            $article->category_id = Request::input('category_id');
            $article->event_type_id = Request::input('event_type_id');
            $article->country = Request::input('country');
            $article->starts = Request::input('starts');
            $article->ends = Request::input('ends');
            $article->organizer = Request::input('organizer');
            $article->address = Request::input('address');
            $article->city = Request::input('city');
            $article->website = Request::input('website');
            $article->email = Request::input('email');
            $article->telephone = Request::input('telephone');
            $article->information = Request::input('information');
            $article->update();


        }


        return redirect(URL::previous());
```

**Line 669 in ArticleController.php**
`$article->subject = Request::input('subject');`

Here is my **editEvent** code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YodwKO

my **articles.blade** code : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjXWOb

**My route:**
`
Route::post('admin/article/update/{type?}/{id?}', [ 'as' => 'update.article', 'uses' => 'ArticleController@update']);

`

Comment: `Line 669`? but it's a controller ... o.o | you also have your logic in the controller.. that should be in the block ..

Comment: I suppose `$article = \App\News::find($id);` is null or empty. The new is not find with id = `$id`. Dump your article after, it will be null

Comment: how to dump it? with dd()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $comm is not defined.  It looks like a typo.

Comment: `$event_comm = EventComment::where('event_id', $id)->get();`, I have this, should I write `$event_comm` instead of `$comm?`

Comment: It looks like you meant it to be $article not $comm

Comment: no bro, shoudn't be $article here, because it is from another table. Please also check `editArticle.blade` /`Articles.blade`